# Server.Transfer call with query string calls current page instead of the given page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I didn't have much luck finding out much about this one…

I have an ASP page that is called from code somewhere else with a query string:

```
[domainpath]/FulfilmentReceipt.aspx?fulfilmentId=226F7486-3D30-439D-92BB-94972234A809
```

In the `Page_Load` there's a `Server.Transfer` call that should move the response execution to another page with a different query string (the `Format()` below appears to work fine BTW):

```
Server.Transfer(String.Format("confirmationReceipt.aspx?bId={0}&f={1}&print=true", basketId, franchiseeId)))
```

The bit I don't understand comes next. The transfer call appears to get routed back to *FulfilmentReceipt.aspx*, the first page, but with the new query string. This then causes an error as the `fulfilmentId` part of the query string is now missing. Why does this not call into `confirmationReceipt` as expected?

I can confirm that `confirmationReceipt` page is never called by debugging into the process and that `fulfilmentReceipt` is loaded twice. There is no code at all in the *Global.asax* file so no routing there and the `confirmationReceipt` page itself has no `Redirect` or `Transfer` calls and is pretty simple.

Additionally the error page rendered in the browser's address bar shows the new query string but as part of the orginal URL. I had thought that the URL seen should not alter as a result of `Server.Transfer`.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

I haven't made any real progress but following Richthofen's advice gave a result of sorts. Using `Response.Redirect` instead of `Server.Transfer` DOES give the desired result when the call is from a browser. But the call is made by a third party library that cannot handle the redirect response.

Trying `Server.Transfer` with the `preserveForm` option makes no difference. To clarify, the transfer ends up calling `FulfilmentReceipt.aspx?bId={0}&f={1}&print=true`. Wrong page, right query string.

**MORE UPDATE**

I have solved my problem by refactoring the `confirmationReceipt` page to accept the query string passed to `fulfilmentReceipt` and changing the `Server.Transfer` call to simply transfer to `confirmationReceipt` without specifying a query string. The transfer than goes to the right place with the original query string.

The question still stands though out of curiosity. Is it simply that `Server.Transfer` cannot deal with urls containing query strings correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that's all it's doing?  Server.Transfer cancels the current request (to FulfilmentReceipt.aspx) and starts a new request.  Unless ConfirmationRecept.aspx redirects to FulfilmentReceipt.aspx, nothing about FulfilmentReceipt.aspx should be executed after Server.Transfer.

Comment: Pretty sure that's all there is. I have not been able to find any other routing in the code.

Comment: Uhm, had a few problems with Server.Transfer just last week. It doesn't stop the execution the way you'd thing it would. Look for something down the line, after the transfer you thing is causing the issue. That's where your problem is most likely situated.

Comment: Thanks linkerro. Did look for that but the transfer is the very last thing on the Page_Load and there are no other functions in the code behind. The confirmation page does appear to dynamically load controls in code but again none of those are very complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As originally posted as an update above I solved my problem by refactoring the confirmationReceipt page to accept the query string passed to fulfilmentReceipt and changing the Server.Transfer call to simply transfer to confirmationReceipt without specifying a query string. The transfer than goes to the right place with the original query string.

It's not ideal as some of the processing is now done twice (converting the query string into something more useful) but it works so I'm happy.

Comment: Cool, thanks for remembering to come back once you cracked it.

Answer (score 0):

Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect are often confused. If you want to pass new query-string values you should use Response.Redirect.

Server.Transfer changes the behavior of a single request being processed by IIS/ASP.NET . It starts a new request on the server, but to the end user, the request is still the same page. you're essentially handing control over to a new page. There's a parameter you can pass, a boolean, to preserve form values. But in general most of the time if you are changing the query string path you should use Response.Redirect so that URL appears in the user's browser (user-agent will receive 302 redirect instead of a 200 OK).

"The transfer call appears to get routed back to FulfilmentReceipt.aspx"

Sounds like confirmationReceipt.aspx probably has a redirect back to "FulfilmentReceipt.aspx". But because you aren't passing 'True', the receipt query string id is lost. Your example might work if you pass 'true' as the second parameter to the Server.Transfer. However, the best bet if it were my code would be to change this out with a Response.Redirect and watch the response trail in Fiddler or another tool to see exactly what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Hi Richthofen, I can't use Response.Redirect as the caller (a third-party library) is not smart enough to handle the redirect response. Server.Transfer seems to be what I need so that the content appears to be from the first Url given. Will try Fiddler...